# while downloading mongodb through brew ,it's showing like this....any solution?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Kuntals-MacBook-Air:~ kuntal$ mongod

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.960+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.962+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.962+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.963+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":14793,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Kuntals-MacBook-Air.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.963+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.5","gitVersion":"ff5cb77101b052fa02da43b8538093486cf9b3f7","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.963+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"20.3.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.963+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.964+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.964+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-06-05T16:16:05.964+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"
```

The Mongod process cannot remove the file at `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` because it doesn't have the right permission. You can manually remove the file `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` then rerun `mongod`

(By the way, consider [formatting the error log](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) next time.)